# WebINK Web fonts not rendering in Firefox

Tags: firefox, webfonts

My website is using Proxima Nova from WebINK and works fine on all browsers (even IE!!) except Firefox. 
I am using the latest FF on a Mac. 
All fonts are rendering as Times

[Here is the link](http://www.drive-tastic.co.uk).

Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Looks fine to me. What version of firefox are you seeing the problem in?

Comment: Agreed, looks fine here ( using Firefox Nightly ): http://note.io/1cbS0Px

Comment: I am using the latest version of Firefox on a mac (25.0.1). Maybe it is OK on a PC, I dont know because I do not own one. Are you seeing a nice sans serif font or Times?

Comment: The funny thing is when I view the site on my local drive using MAMP and going to localhost:8888... etc - it looks fine . Its just when it is on the server (Hostgator)